# Why does French use a "split negative"?

Tags: grammaire, histoire, négation

I'm referring to such constructions as *ne [verb] pas*, *ne [verb] que*, *ne [verb] jamais*, etc.

In Spanish, the negative precedes the verb:

- ***No** lo quiero.*

In Anglo-Saxon languages, the negative follows the (helping) verb:

- *I do **not** like that.*
- *Doch das Messer, sieht man **nicht**.*

So do the two different parts of the French negative perform different functions in the negation?

And what about the times when it seems like *ne* is superfluous? As in "*Pas du tout* ".

Comment: Notice that _ne_ tends to be (errouneously) omitted, for example: _je comprends pas la question_, so who knows, maybe in the distant future it won't exist anymore.

Comment: Quite interested by this one: I know that the *split negative* (which I think is called « négation renforcée » in French) is a relatively recent phenomenon. Indeed, the simple negative construct (« je ne sais si je l'aime ») is still used in literary style. But I don't know more than that, and I'd love to learn!

Comment: There is a name to this phenomenon that happens in many languages where the preverb negation slowly becomes post-verb. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jespersen%27s_Cycle

Comment: @Karnn: Thanks for that Wikipedia entry.

Comment: This may help: http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/fr-qui-ne-dit-mot-consent.50282/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Grevisse:

> Primitivement, la négation portant sur un verbe est exprimée par l'adverbe *ne*, et celui peut encore suffire dans certaines circonstances. Le plus souvent cependant, on recourt à la fois à *ne* et à un auxiliaire, adverbe, déterminant ou pronom. Ces auxiliaires, qui n'avaient pas de sens négatif à l'origine ont fini par prendre eux-même ce sens négatif et par pouvoir s'employer négativement sans *ne*.
>
> [...]
>
> La forme atone *ne* [de *non* qui provient du latin *non*], négation ordinaire dans la langue du moyen âge, a été de très bonne heure renforcée par des noms désignant une petite quantité, une petite étendue, une chose de valeur insignifiante : *pas*, *point*, *mie* (= miette), *goutte*, *mot*, *noix*, *pois*, *espi*, *dé*, *bouton*, *denier*, *pomme*, [...] Les plus fréquents de ces compléments ont perdu leur valeur propre pour devenir de simples auxiliaires de la négation. Le choix ne s'est pas opéré de la même façon partout : il y a des dialectes où l'auxiliaire normal est *point* ; d'autres où c'est *mie* ; etc.

Il y a 16 pages qui suivent pour décrire les manières de nier un verbe dans mon édition du *bon usage* plus 6 qui traitent du *ne explétif*.  J'ai eu l'idée un temps de les résumer, j'abandonne.

---

English summary: in old French, *ne* was used alone, and it still can be sometimes. Soon additional words were used for emphasis. Nowadays those additional words often must be used. While they didn't have a negative meaning at the start, they acquired one and may now be used in some contexts without *ne* in their negative meaning.

There are 16 pages describing the way to negate a verb in my edition of *le bon usage*, plus 6 describing the *ne explétif* where *ne* isn't used to negate.  I played with the idea of summarizing them, but dropped it.

Comment: Most amusing: when speaking, the `ne` is often omitted: `je pense pas` - but this is incorrect French. However, in (archaic) writing, the `pas` is omitted: `je ne pense` - this **is** correct.

Comment: Interesting! Is "pas" therefore the same word as the noun "un pas" (a step)? I get that impression when looking at the helper words (a crumb, nut, drop, button, etc.). It seems to make sense in the same way English would say "I don't like it **one bit**".

Comment: @Konerak, things are more complex that that. Omitting _ne_ is far too common to qualify it as incorrect (Grevisse just describes the usage but usually mentions when common usage is not considered valid by some, he doesn't here). It occurs not only when speaking but also when writing, at least for some helper words like _rien_. On the other hand, _ne_ is sometimes always used without an helper word, sometimes the helper word is optional (and more so in writing than when speaking) and sometimes (like a standalone _Je ne pense._) we never do it.

Comment: @Andrew, it is exactly that.

Answer (score 19):

In the oldest time, you could have the "strong" form *non*, hence *nonobstant*, *nonchalant*, *non-recevoir*... But the most common form of the negation was in fact *ne* alone. Eventually emphatic elements were added, which varied depending on context: *Je ne mange mie* ("I don't eat a crumb"), *je ne vois goutte* ("I can't see a drop [of water]"), *je n'avance pas* ("I don't move a step"), *je ne dis mot* ("I don't speak a word").... most of those are still considered valid literary usage.

Eventually the "auxiliary" (as Grevisse calls them) to the negation became obligatory in many contexts. Grevisse (Le Bon usage., 14e ed., §§1012-1019) does not explain exactly why *pas* evolved from being used with verbs of movement to become the most common of these auxiliaries, then the default one. The [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pas) (Trésor de la Langue Française informatisé), however, notes that the usage dates right back from the 12th century, so although it was not the standard of negation at the time, it is a feature of French almost from its birth.

Some dialects have gone in different directions and have other adverbs as the default auxiliary. If you want to get into the real nitty-gritty, you'll probably need to look at more technical literature like the bibliography in the TLFi's entry

Answer (score 9):

(Copying parts of [another answer of mine](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1912/770).)

Originally, *ne* is what makes the negation. The etymology of "pas" and "jamais" are exactly the opposite of their current meaning because of this. The only remainder (and cause of ambiguity is "plus"). There is a direct parallel with *not* and *ever/more* in English.

For example, "*Je (ne) mange jamais de bonbons*" ("ne" is rarely used in speech) would mean "I (n)ever eat sweets.". No one today would understand *jamais* in this context to mean *ever* or *always*: it's always understood as *never*. However, there are cases where the "*ever*" meaning is still used. [For example](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1912/770): "*Il court plus vite que jamais.*" (More than *ever*).

I'm not aware of any similar example with "pas" (although my understanding is that it comes from similar Latin roots and constructs).

There is still an ambiguity when you say "*J'ai plus de bonbons.*"

- If you pronounce "plusse", it's meant as it's written ("I have more sweets.")
- If you pronounce "plu", *ne* is implied and should be written "*Je n'ai plus de bonbons.*" (i.e. *no* more).

---

In addition, linking *ne* to the verb allows you to negate verbs in a way that can be quite tricky in English. For example:

- "Je peux ne pas faire quelque chose." -> "(I may) (not do something)", which is completely the opposite of "I may not do something" (i.e. I'm not allowed to).
- "Ca peut ne pas marcher pour telle ou telle raison." -> "(It can) (not work)", whereas "can not" (or cannot) would have a completely different meaning.
- In English, you also get split infinitives (at least in common speech) quite regularly because of this. "Je fais ceci pour ne pas faire ca." would often be said (incorrectly) as "I do this to *not* do that."

Comment: "plus" is not the only remainder of words with dual opposite meanings. "pas" (Je ne marche pas/I walk no step), "personne" (Je ne vois personne/I see no body) and even "rien" (Il n'y a rien/There is no thing) like in "des petits riens".

Comment: In english, the difference would be "i can not do something" and "i cannot/can't do something"

Comment: @BenKnoble sure, but "I can not do something" is incorrect in English anyway.

Comment: I'd say then I cannot do anything, right?

Comment: @5915961T I meant "something" as in "something specific". You'd generally use "I can avoid to ..." or "I'm able not to ..." in English, but that doesn't always work directly. For example, if you can avoid to go through B while going from A to C, you'd say "je peux ne pas passer par B pour aller de A à C", but "I can not go through B to go from A to C" isn't correct in English (and would generally be read as "I cannot go through...", which more or less means that B is blocked).

Comment: @Bruno it's not actually incorrect: it is sometimes used for emphasis (said with emphasis on every word as if in a drumbeat) "I can not do that", to express the negative "I can *not* do that" as in I have the option of not doing it, and it's also necessary in some constructions: "I can not only do that, but I can do you one better." Try writing that as "I cannot only do that, but I have to do this as well." and suddenly it means you have to do that, and also something else. See the excellent answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4510/why-is-cannot-spelled-as-one-word)

Answer (score 5):

The origin of the "auxilliaire de négation **pas**" is not clear. I still found a page in [Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:cHr4-YuDqhAJ:research.jyu.fi/pisantorni/gr/491.html+origine+de+l%27auxiliaire+de+n%C3%A9gation&cd=15&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=fr&lr=lang_de%7Clang_fr%7Clang_ja%7Clang_en&client=opera) for Finnish student learning french. It also seems to be kind of confirmed by the [Wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pas). To be noted, the real negation is the "adverbe **ne**" and not the auxiliary.

> [FR] Le mot pas est au départ un simple nom qui servait à renforcer la négation. Il subsiste d’autres noms de ce type, mais nettement moins fréquents : ne … point (= ne … pas), utilisé dans langue soutenue ou dans un usage régional ; ne … mot, ne … goutte sont littéraires et se sont conservés dans quelques expressions plus ou moins figées :

[EN] The word **pas** was originally a simple noun which was used to reinforce the negation. It persists other noun of this type, but less frequent : ne … point (= ne … pas), used in formal language or regional usage; ne … mot, ne … goutte are literary and have been conserved in fixed expressions.

> Il n’y a point d’autre solution.
>
> Il n’a dit mot.
>
> On n’y voit goutte.
>
> Je n’y comprends goutte.

Comment: "Mot" aussi? je vois: "mie, goutte, pas et point " ici: http://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Grammaire_%C3%A9l%C3%A9mentaire_de_l%E2%80%99ancien_fran%C3%A7ais/Chapitre_5 J'ai du mal à voir "mot" comme un adverbe

Comment: Sinon, il y a _pas_, _point_, _nullement_ (_aucunement_, _mie_), _rien_, _nul_, _personne_, _aucun_, _jamais_, _guère_, _plus_, _nulle part_ et j'arrête ici de chercher.

Comment: Oui, il n'y a *que* l'embarras du choix.

Answer (score 5):

It's a manifestation of [Jespersen's cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jespersen%27s_Cycle).

Old English and Old French negated words with a simple particle, inherited directly from Proto-Indo-European:

- (Old French) *io ne marche*
- (Old French) *io ne meniu*
- (Old English) *ic ne cnāwe*

But the speakers of Middle French and Middle English came to think of the negation particle as being too difficult to hear, and so augmented the negation by adding an additional word:

- (Middle French) *je ne marche pas*
- (Middle French) *je ne menje mie*
- (Middle English) *i ne knowe naht*

Originally, *pas* was used with movement words, and other words were used in other contexts, like *mie* 'crumb' and *goutte* 'drop'. But eventually, *pas* was generalized as the negative word, and became mandatory, while English dropped the original negation entirely.

- (Modern French) *Je ne marche pas.*
- (Modern French) *Je ne mange pas.*
- (Early Modern English) *I know not.*

The standardized varieties of French preserve this situation, while the colloquial varieties follow English down the cycle by dropping *ne* entirely. (Although English took a detour by requiring *not* to be attached to *do*.)

- (Colloquial French) *Je marche pas.*
- (Colloquial French) *Je mange pas.*
- (Modern English) *I do not know.* -> *I don't know.*

The same thing happened in all other Germanic languages, *ich weiß es nicht*, *ik weet het niet*, *jeg vet ikke*, and it's easy to imagine a future form of French losing *ne* entirely, colloquial or not. But who knows.

Answer (score 4):

From a linguistic viewpoint, the negation isn't split, merely transformed immediately before final utterance.  *Ne* is phonologically a single word, and historically a single syntactic structure, as is *pas*.  Today *ne . . . pas*, while two words, is a single syntactic structure.  The redundancy improves intelligibility, and the separation serves to delimit the verb or verbal.  My French is passable, but I am not a native speaker, and will have to depend on parallels in English.

Two analogous structures exist in English:  the progressive and the perfect.  Applying each in turn to *they go* yields *they are going* and *they have gone*. In both cases the verb is encapsulated within a single auxiliary structure, as French verbs are encapsulated in *ne . . . pas*.  Linguists write this as a transformation of something called a K-terminal string:

they + pres. +  (be + ing)   + go -->  they + (pres. + be) + (ing + go) --> *they are going*

they + pres. + (have + part) + go --> they + (pres. + have) + (part + go) --> *they have gone*

You've got to have tense, and be takes tense, and the subject is *they*, so it's *are*. The verb is *go*, and all verbs take *ing*, so it's *going*. The structure (have + participle) works the same way.

The foregoing may look a little brain-damaged, but it's remarkably efficient.  The whole rule for auxiliary in English (neglecting passive and subjunctive, which are sentence transformations) is:

Aux => (tense) + {modal} + {have + part} + {be + ing}

where the parentheses indicate that tense is obligatory and the curly braces indicate that everything else is optional.

So with two tenses, past and present, and five modals--will, shall, can, may, must--you can generate a pageful of ways to link a verb with its auxiliaries, including the more recondite forms such as *would have been giving*. Note that this rule doesn't link the whole verbal to the subject--that's a different animal called the s-form rule, which is applied over the auxiliary.

To negate an affirmative sentence in modern English, the transformation is quite simple:  apply *not* after the first word in the auxiliary.  It goes there because the auxiliary delimits the truth of the whole sentence, both in time and condition.  In the cases of simple past and present, when you haven't got an auxiliary form for *not* to follow, you can put it after a be, but not a verb.  You have to supply a *do* for the *not* to follow.  If you simply apply the Do transformation to an affirmative sentence, that will emphasize its truth value, but a *do* followed by a *not* serves merely as a sort of pre-affirmation.

*Pas du tout* and similar forms like *pas de problem* don't negate sentences, so the structure *ne . . . pas* is not required.  The postfixed emphatic *pas* is analogous to the prefixed English emphatic *do*, and the archaic use of *ne* without *pas* is analogous to archaic English forms like "Say not the struggle naught availeth."

Comment: I find that comparing the French negation (ne...pas) and English composite tenses a bit of a stretch. Just because there is the encapsulation in those two different forms does not mean there is an analogy here.

Answer (score 3):

I lighted upon this question at [r/asklinguistics](https://old.reddit.com/r/asklinguistics/comments/6bxx9n/how_did_the_french_negative_form_ne_pas_or_ne/dhqfmb1/):

> [TomSFox](https://old.reddit.com/user/TomSFox). 
>   25 points 2 years ago
>
> There is a phenomenon called the [Jespersen’s Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jespersen%27s_Cycle), whereby the force of the negative adverb weakens over time and has to be reinforced by an additional expression, for example by saying something like “not one bit” (as in, “I did **not** like it **one bit**.”) or, as was the case in Latin, “not one step” (“nec … passum”), which over time evolved into “ne … pas” in French.

McWhorter, J. [PhD  Linguistics (Stanford)](https://americanstudies.columbia.edu/people/john-h-mcwhorter) expounds on pp. 26-27 of [*The Power of Babel* (2003)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/006052085X). I post a screenshot; I don't know how to replicate its formatting with SE's tools.

> [image]