# Le sens de « ne » dans « ils ne pouvaient espérer mieux »

Tags: grammaire, usage, expressions-idiomatiques, négation

Lors de la lecture de [cet article](http://www.lemonde.fr/euro2012/article/2012/06/23/euro-2012-les-bleus-quittent-l-euro-la-tete-basse_1723736_1616919.html), j'ai remarqué la phrase suivante:

> Les hommes de Laurent Blanc pourront dire qu'ils ont rempli leur objectif en se qualifiant pour les quarts de finale. Au vu du jeu proposé lors des deux derniers matchs, **ils ne pouvaient espérer mieux**.

Je le traduis comme:

> … they could not hope for more/better.

Le *ne* dans cette expression est clairement utilisé pour former la négation, pas pour l'accentuation, mais il ne possède pas d'auxiliaire négatif.  Alors, est-ce que c'est un exemple parmi « quelques expressions figées » qui sont ainsi utilisées en français moderne, ou une typo?

Comment: Voir aussi les réponses de http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/884

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grevisse note (14<sup>e</sup> ed. §1014 b. 1º) que c'est une des constructions courantes où *ne* s'emploie sans auxiliaire (il appelle *auxiliaire* la seconde partie de la formule de négation). Plus exactement, ne+pouvoir+infinitif est la construction en question (*oser*, *cesser* et *manquer de* peuvent aussi l'employer).

Il note que dans l'ensemble, la langue écrite formelle tend à inclure "beaucoup plus de *ne* seuls qu'il n'en est prévu" par les constructions qu'il mentionne. Personnellement, je crois que les exemples qu'il donne pour démontrer cela sont nettement archaïsants.

Comment: On peut avoir les exemples ? :-)

Comment: Bah, ce sont des cas d'emplois de *ne* comme seul adverbe de négation sans construction spécifique, et en ce sens, c'est archaïsant. En voici deux (parce que c'est pas pratique à recopier, hein XD): "N'a-t-il altéré certains textes? N'en a-t-il présenté quelques-uns avec un très léger gauchissement?" (Mauriac, *Blaise Pascal et sa sœur Jacqueline*), "Il est extrêmement rare que la compagnie des femmes ne me divertisse." (Sartre, *Carnets de la Drôle de Guerre*)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez — Tu as sans doute noté l'exemple auto-référent : « beaucoup plus de ne seuls qu'il **n**'en est prévu ». On parle de *ne explétif*.

Comment: @Lierre Moi je ne l'avais pas remarqué XD ET je ne saurais dire si c'était dans l'original ou si je l'ai ajouté inconsciemment (je ne suis pas chez moi en ce moment).

Comment: @Lierre: Oui, j'avais bien noté, mais j'ai été déçu de constater qu'il s'agissait justement d'un *ne* explétif. Et ce n'est donc pas un exemple auto-référent. Je voulais des exemples de *ne* qui ont vraie valeur de négation et qui ne sont pas désuets. Je pense qu'il en existe mais je ne saurais en trouver. (Ah ben peut-être que j'en tiens un là ?… La phrase précédente vous paraît-elle vraiment archaïque ?)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Oui, mais ce qui m'accroche c'est plutôt que j'aurais écrit "je ne saurais où chercher".

Comment: @Circeus: En effet, *être capable d'en trouver* aurait été plus naturel que *savoir trouver* ici. Mais ton exemple avec *savoir où chercher* fonctionne pareil, si on rajoute l'adverbe *pas*, la phrase devient étrange. Ça donne l'impression que l'incapacité est concrète, alors qu'on est pourtant dans une situation hypothétique. Ce qui importe c'est plutôt qu'elle met en doute l'hypothèse.

Answer (score 3):

En effet, votre traduction est juste. Dans cette phrase le mot "pas" est sous-entendu : "Ils ne pouvaient pas espérer mieux". L'utilisation de l'adverbe "ne ... pas" est le moyen de négation le plus utilisé en français. C'est donc plutôt une forme grammaticale. Vous trouverez plus d'informations dans l'[article sur la négation](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%A9gation_en_fran%C3%A7ais) de Wikipédia.

Comment: La section sur l'emploi de *ne* seul est bien maigre dans cet article Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

C'est un cas particulier de l'ellipse du mot « pas » dans une négation car il s'agit bien d'une négation. C'est un emploi littéraire ou bien qui convient à un registre soutenu de la langue parlée ; il ne convient en tant que langue moderne que pour 3 verbes lorsque ceux-ci sont suivis d'un infinitif.

- avoir, pouvoir, savoir

Selon le même schéma d'utilisation il convient aussi pour 3 verbes lorsque suivis de la conjonction « que » puis d'un infinitif.

- cesser, pouvoir, savoir

Dans les cas considérés ci-dessus il y a toujours la possibilité d'utiliser « pas ». Il existe cependant un cas de cette ellipse pour de rares  éléments figés qui sont des proverbes ou des expressions usuelles dont le verbe dans la construction négative n'est pas d'un type particulier et pour lesquels *il n'est pas possible d'utiliser* « pas » dans beaucoup de cas.

- Qui ne dit mot consent.
- Qu'à cela ne tienne. (* assez courant*)
- Si je ne me trompe (pas), [vous êtes le concierge…/il a neigé ce jour-là./c'est votre fils./…] (*assez courant*) (Wikipédia, négation en français)
- <s>Si je ne fais erreur…</s>, <s>Si je ne manque un cas…</s>, <s>Si je ne fausse le mécanisme…</s>, …
- À Dieu ne plaise ! (*pas courant*) (Wikipédia, négation en français)

On trouve la plupart des informations fournies ci-dessus dans cette [page web](http://www.bertrandboutin.ca/Folder_151_Grammaire/O_a_la_negation.htm), laquelle donne en plus un très complet résumé de toute les pratiques en matière d'utilisation de la négation en français.