# What is the grammatical reason to use "n'ont pu" instead of "n'ont pas pu"?

Tags: grammaire, négation

My understanding of the French grammar rule is that "ne" and "pas" come together for negations. But, apparently, it is not so in the following case:

Beaucoup de gens n'ont pu en revenir vivants

Maybe, there is an exception to this rule in this case. Could somebody explain to me about the exception in this case? (I am aware of the other exceptions, such as "ne ~ que" and "ne ~rien" or "ne ~ jamais")

Comment: This is  recurrent question. You will find answers [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/2785/358) and [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/22304/358).There are probably more.

Answer (score 2):

*Ne* est un adverbe de négation. Il est en général accompagné de "pas, point, guère, jamais, etc", mais ce n'est pas une obligation.

"Beaucoup de gens n'ont pu en revenir vivants" est parfaitement correct et n'est pas une exception. On aurait parfaitement pu écrire "Beaucoup de gens n'ont pas pu en revenir vivants" mais ici cela "sonne" moins bien et n'apporte rien, la première phrase étant parfaitement compréhensible.

En revanche, dans de nombreux cas, le "pas" est nécessaire pour une bonne compréhension, par exemple dans "je n'ai pas mangé ce midi".

il s'agit donc plus d'un problème de compréhension, et de style, que de règle grammaticale stricte.

En revanche, le "j'ai pas mangé ce midi" est une faute, ce qui confirme que la négation provient bien du "ne". À noter que cette faute (l'absence du *ne*) est devenue une habitude dans le langage parlé.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101020/discussion-on-answer-by-damien-what-is-the-grammatical-reason-to-use-nont-pu).