# Dans quelle(s) mesure(s) peut-on omettre le « ne » ?

Tags: oral, négation

J'ai lu quelque part qu'en français parlé (informel), il est courant d'omettre le « ne » pour former la négation. Par exemple : « je parle pas allemand », ou « je sais pas ».

Mais en lisant *Harry Potter et la Chambre Des Secrets* en français, j'ai remarqué que les dialogues (« parlés ») utilisaient toujours le « ne ».

Quelles sont les règles ?

S'il vous plaît, répondez en français **et** en anglais, si vous avez le loisir d'en écrire autant.

Comment: Si quelqu'un a un avis sur ma correction, il est le très bienvenu à l'exprimer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ce que tu as lu est exact, je ∅ vais pas te mentir, énormément de ces *ne* disparaissent à l'oral. Par exemple, [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/884/why-does-french-use-a-split-negative) (en anglais) parle du sujet, et [ce genre de commentaires](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/884/why-does-french-use-a-split-negative#comment1619_886) peut être pertinent.

Il me semble que le problème dans *Harry Potter* tient à ce que tu lis des dialogues « parlés »… **écrits**. Dans le premier bouquin qui me passe sous la main aussi, les discours censés être oraux — mais **transcrits** à l'écrit (ça reste un livre) — font figurer tous les *ne* qui disparaissent le plus souvent à l'oral, le vrai.

Mais je serais fort surpris que ces *ne* soient dans le film, par exemple.

---

What you read is correct, most of these *ne* are omitted in oral speech. [This question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/884/why-does-french-use-a-split-negative) is of interest, especially [this kind of comments](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/884/why-does-french-use-a-split-negative#comment1619_886).

What I think is wrong in your observation is that the book you're reading is, well, **a book, *written* text**. Thus the negative forms are fully expanded and no words are missing. Grabbing a book featuring “oral speech”, all the *ne* are in place, because it being a book overrules what supposedly is written.

I wouldn't expect these *ne* to be kept in the movie, for instance.

Answer (score 4):

L'absence de "*ne*" dans les phrases négatives relève du langage familier en général. C'est plus qu'une tournure orale comme le dit Nikana.

---

The lack of "*ne*" in negative sentences comes under colloquial language in general. It is more than an oral turn just like Nikana says.

Answer (score 3):

A very long story.

When reading a book I expect "*Je ne sais pas*", I would be surprised to read anything else.
However, when reading it loudly, I'd probably say "*J'sais pas*", and if I am asked to repeat I'd say "*Je n'sais pas*" or "*Je sais pas*" or "*J'en sais rien*"or "*Je n'en sais rien*", depending on the reason I am asked to repeat.

More example [here](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/negation_inf.htm).

These forms are perfectly good french, and the reason why to use one or the other depends on the moment.

I suggest you use the forms you as you read them. With time, you will learn which word and letters french speakers allow you to skip without looking at it as laziness.

---

C’est une longue histoire.

Dans un livre, je m’attends à "*Je ne sais pas*", et je serais surpris de lire quoi que ce soit d’autre .Mais, en le lisant à haute voix, je prononcerais probablement  "*J'sais pas*". Et si on me demande de répéter, je dirais "*Je n'sais pas*" ou "*Je sais pas*" ou "*Je n'en ai aucune idée*", selon la raison pour laquelle on m’a demandé de répéter.

Tu trouveras des exemples [ici](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/negation_inf.htm).

Ces différentes formes sont toutes en français correct et la raison d’utiliser l’une ou l’autre dépend des circonstances.

Je suggère d’apprendre la forme *livresque* et de laisser le temps te montrer quels mots et lettres les locuteurs français te laisse élider sans passer pour paresseux.

---

(C’t) une longue histoire.

Dans un livre, j’m’attends à "*Je ne sais pas*", et j’s’rais surpris d’ lire quoi qu’ce(e) soit d’autre. Mais, en le(e) lisant à haut’ voix, j’prononc’rais probabl’ment  "*J'sais pas*". Et si on me d'mand’ de(e) répéter, j’dirais "*Je n'sais pas*" ou "*Je sais pas*" ou "*J’en sais rien*" ou "*Je n’en sais rien*", selon la raison qu’on m’a d’mandé de(e) répéter.

Y’a plus d’exemples [ici](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/negation_inf.htm).

Ces différentes formes sont toutes correctes et on **n'** utilise l’une ou l’autre selon les circonstancese.

Comment: Tiens, j'aurais plutôt dit « si on me d'mande d'répéter ». Et j'ajouterais que « j'sais pas » n'est pas très naturel et a tendance à devenir « chais pas ».

Comment: Très juste, merci. Comme quoi il y a tout de même une règle, que j'utilise et qui est la même que celle utilisée par Gilles.