# What is “C'est pas d'sa faute!”?

Tags: prononciation, oral, négation

I'm French study beginner, so I don't have so much knowledge about French 
but I'm trying to read a book, in which I found the sentence
“*c'est pas d'sa faute*”.

What does “*d'sa*” mean in this sentence and why is it not “*ce n'est pas d'sa faute*”?

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming that sentence was part of a dialogue. The character is speaking in a familiar register of French, so the author is not writing in proper French to get that fact across.

In oral familiar French, it is common to drop the final *e* and kind of glue the next word to it. So *d'sa* is actually *de sa* elided together.

It is also very common to drop the double particle negative in oral French and omit *ne* altogether. You are correct, it should be *Ce n'est pas*, but with the *ne* omitted, it does become *C'est pas*.

Answer (score 5):

There are two questions here.

- *d'sa* is a simple elision of *de sa*.
- *ne* is omitted because it is fading out in oral French. [And we already have a question about that](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/4578/82)

So this is a common realisation of « *ce n'est pas de sa faute* » in oral French.

Comment: @KIM It could even be shortened again by saying: _« C'est pas d'sa faute »_ (not really correct but often found in oral speaking)

Comment: @JeromeJ Do you mean « *c'est pas sa faute* » ?

Comment: Why not. I mainly wanted to insist on the beginning of the sentence, saying that _« C'est pas […] »_ is often used instead of _« Ce n'est pas […] »_. But it's true that _« d' »_ can also be drop, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not his/her fault! But it's a very familiar expression, the correct one would be ”*Ce n'est pas de sa faute*”.