# Confused on the translation of "de pas faire"

Tags: sens, négation

I'm not sure I understand the use of "de pas faire" completely.  I thought it mean "to not do" but the phrase "libre de pas faire comme on nous dit" seems to translate as "free to do as we are told" instead of "free to not do as we are told".

What am I missing?

Comment: You should give a full sentence, but here it's clear: this is an example of omitting *ne*, which is common in colloquial French. See [Dans quelle(s) mesure(s) peut-on omettre le « ne » ?](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/4578), [négation en français](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%A9gation_en_fran%C3%A7ais) (I don't have a reference in English but any grammar book would do).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The proper construct would be “*libre de **ne** pas faire*” (which might indeed become “*libre de pas faire*” in familiar settings).

I would indeed translate “*Libre de ne pas faire comme on nous dit.*” as “Free not to do as we’re told”, as in “I might choose to ignore what you tell me and do something else”, **not** as in “I might choose to do what you tell me to”.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, there's a difference between

> Ceci est à ne pas faire (literally, *This is to not do*)

meaning this **has** to not be done (please don't do it), and

> Ceci n'est pas à faire (literally, *This is not to do*)

meaning this is not needed (but could eventually, if you really want).