# "Je ne doute point d'apprendre"

Tags: grammaire, négation, francais-classique

*En français dans le texte*, from Shakespeare's [*Henry V*](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/1784) [Act 3 Scene 4](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1784/pg1784.html#id00127):

> Katherine — Je ne doute point d'apprendre [...] et en peu de temps.

Meaning “I have no doubt learned et in a short time”.

What grammatical purpose does “*point de*” serve in this sentence?

Comment: Rather, “I *will* no doubt learn” — literally (and expressed in a similar old-fashioned way), “I doubt not that I shall learn”.

Comment: See also http://french.stackexchange.com/a/886/176

Answer (score 9):

"*Je ne doute point*" is another way of saying "*je ne doute pas*". It is a [negative](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/n%C3%A9gation), it is very formal and sounds old fashioned nowadays but might have been standard French is the 16th century.

Comment: Vous avez complètement raison. J'ai vu souvent cette construction dans la littérature française... par exemple, _Le bourgeois gentilhomme_ de Molière.