# Should "il n'y en a point" be converted into "il n'y en a pas" or "il n'y en a rien" in everyday speech?

Tags: grammaire, négation

> Les résultats… Jusqu'ici, il n'y en a point.

I suppose that the word "point" in this specific sense is not used nowadays, so should I convert it into "pas" or "rien" in this sentence?

Comment: Doesn't the answer to [this question](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/7838/358) on *ne... point* answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Point*** which is indeed outdated, even in regional usage, can be replaced by ***pas*** here while keeping the sentence very same meaning:

> Les résultats… Jusqu'ici il n'y en a pas.

If you want to use ***rien***, you might write:

> Les résultats… Jusqu'ici, rien !

Comment: Thanks. So the translation should be something like "So far, there isn't any of those"?

Comment: Probably but the lack of context, as often happens, doesn't help figuring out what kind of results this is about.