# Le sens, la provenance et l’emploi de « point du tout »

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, négation, littérature

J’ai une question sur une tournure que j’ai rencontré [dans le livre *L’épave du Cynthia*](http://beq.ebooksgratuits.com/vents-xpdf/Verne-Cynthia.pdf), écrit au dix-neuvième siècle par Jules Verne.

Malarius est un enseignant à une école.  Docteur Schwaryencrona, un vieil ami à lui le surprend quand il entre dans la salle soudainement. Il était heureux de le revoir. Vous voyez ci-dessous un morceau de la causerie qu’ils tiennent.  Voici le propos de l’enseignant, suivi par la repartie de son copain.

> « Mon cher ami, mon bon, mon excellent docteur ! disait-il. Nous
>   n’allons pas rester ici. Je vais donner congé à tous ces malandrins,
>   qui n’en seront pas fâchés, assurément, et nous passerons chez moi...
>
> *Point du tout*, déclara le docteur en se retournant vers les élèves, qui suivaient avec un vif intérêt les détails de cette scène. Je ne
>   dois ni te déranger dans tes travaux ni troubler les études de cette
>   belle jeunesse !...

Ma question porte sur *point du tout*. Je sais que « pas de tout » et « ne … point » sont deux façons d’exprimer qu’un avis va à l’encontre de l’avis qu’une autre personne vient de donner. 
Je dirais que ces deux manières de dire se sont entrelacées ici, et que le résultat veut dire la même chose que les deux tournures dont il est issu.

Mes pensées sur le sens et la provenance de la façon de dire, semblent-elles valables ?
Peut-elle encore être utilisée ou est-elle vieillie ?

Comment: Voir http://french.stackexchange.com/a/886 pour l'origine de l'usage de pas, point, mie, ... comme auxiliaire de négation.  J'ai jamais vu utiliser autre chose que _pas_ et _point_ avec _x du tout_.

Comment: @Unfrancophone Il y a aussi au moins *plus du tout* et *rien du tout*.

Comment: @jlliagre, avec un sens différent dans les deux cas. _Pas du tout_ et _point du tout_ sont synonymes.

Comment: @Unfrancophone C'est vrai mais le commentaire auquel je répondais ne précisait pas cette restriction et semblait donc indiquer que les seuls auxiliaires de négation utilisés dans *x du tout* étaient *pas* et *point*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Point*, comme adverbe de négation, est désuet. À l'époque de Jules Verne, il est déjà minoritaire par rapport à *pas*. De nos jours, on ne l'utilise plus du tout en français standard.

[image: ne point / ne pas,n ' est point / n ' est pas,point du tout / pas du tout]

« Point du tout » et « pas du tout » sont synonymes. La locution « du tout » ([TLF tout³](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tout) B) renforce la négation ; on peut l'utiliser aussi dans « rien du tout » ou « sans … du tout » mais pas avec d'autres adverbes de négation comme *jamais*, *personne* ou *aucun*.

> Je n'aime pas du tout les épinards.
>   Je ne vois rien du tout.

On peut utiliser « pas du tout » tout seul pour exprimer son opposition complète à ce qu'a dit l'interlocuteur. Ces expressions sont à peu près synonymes :

> Pas du tout !
>   (Bien) au contraire !
>   Mais non !

Dans le contexte de la citation de Jules Verne, « point du tout » est une manière polie de refuser une proposition qui coûterait à celui qui la propose. Elle exprime en gros « cette proposition est généreuse, mais je ne veux pas que vous vous dérangiez ». On peut aussi l'utiliser dans la situation symétrique :

> — Je vous propose de vous accompagner.
>   — Cela me serait d'un grand secours. Vous être trop aimable !
>   — Pas du tout ! C'est tout naturel.

Answer (score 0):

En dehors des explications fournies dans les réponses à la question *[Why does French use a "split negative"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/884)*, on utilisera surtout *pas du tout*  de façon péremptoire alors *point du tout* annoncera une explication, une justification :

> - *Pas du tout !* Ce que vous dites est faux, ma réponse est non.
> - *Point du tout !* Ce n'est pas ainsi que les choses se sont passées ...

Dans le premier exemple la voix aura des tonalités autoritaires, vives, dans le second elle aura un rythme didactique, apaisé.

Ici, le *pas* est une négation absolue, le *point* pointe vers une résistance, une controverse à mettre en lumière.

Mais ils peuvent être inter-changés sans modifier le sens de la phrase, seule l'intention de l'auteur et le contexte choisissent le mot qui convient.

Comment: Voir ce qui peut être tiré de la remarque su r[cette page](http://www.espacefrancais.com/difference-entre-pas-et-point/): j'avoue ne pas être convaincue par ce qui est dit sur « l'exclusion partielle » et « l'exclusion totale » mais que ça pourrait peut-être être creusé.

Comment: @Laure Tout à fait d'accord. De même pour les  §5 & 6 sur la qualité et les nombres, *point* n'est jamais utilisé 'naturellement' ; sur le § suivant je ne fais pas du tout le même lecture, et j'aurais pratiquement répondu l'inverse.  Ce n'est pas parce que cela contredit ma réponse, mais dans l'ensemble, j'ai l'impression d'avoir un site de réponses théoriques qui ne répondent pas dans le sens de ce j'ai vécu, de ce que j'emploie intuitivement.

Comment: « On utilisera » ? Non, tout au plus on *utilisait*, et encore je ne suis pas du tout convaincu de cette différence, je demande à voir une étude sérieuse. En français moderne, on n'utilise plus *point* comme négation.

Comment: @Gilles - C'est ainsi que je l'entends : *point*  n'est pas une négation stricte comme *pas*, ce n'est un mur perpendiculaire sur lequel l'affirmation va s'écraser et être 'détruite', mais un mur oblique sur lequel elle va rebondir dans une autre direction et apporter un changement de point de vue. Il me semble que *point* est beaucoup plus soutenu, donc d'un emploi écrit et recherché, ou inclus dans des locutions, mais très rare dans les conversations. «  On utilisera » donne des pistes d'utilisation, j'aurai peut-être dû le mettre à la première personne pour enlever le caractère péremptoire.