# Grammar about the idiomatic expression "qn. ne pouvait rêver meilleur(e) + noun"

Tags: grammaire

> Il ***ne pouvait rêver meilleure*** façon d'occuper son temps libre.

1. In this specific expression, is it more common to drop "pas"?

> Il ne pouvait (***pas***) rêver meilleure façon d'occuper son temps libre.

2. The lack of an article "une" or "de" immediately before "meilleure" has me curious. Why this omission?

> Il ne pouvait rêver (***une*** / ***de***) meilleure façon d'occuper son temps libre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ces bizarreries sont des constructions vieillies. De nos jours, on ne les emploie que dans des textes littéraires.

Lorsque le français se différenciait progressivement du latin, la négation s'exprimait simplement avec une particule qui a dérivé de *non* en *ne*. Lorsque le verbe n'avait pas de complément, on s'est mis à en ajouter un, par exemple « je ne vois *rien* » (*rien* signifiant *chose*). Au fil des siècles, l'ajout d'une deuxième particule négative s'est généralisée, avec *pas* comme particule par défaut. En français moderne, *ne* sans une deuxième particule est littéraire (et en langue familière, on omet souvent *ne*). Pour plus de détails, voir [Why does French use a "split negative"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/884/why-does-french-use-a-split-negative) et [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%A9gation_en_fran%C3%A7ais#.C3.89volution_de_l.27expression_de_la_n.C3.A9gation).

En latin, la plupart des groupes nominaux n'ont pas d'article. En français, l'article défini (*le/la/les*) et l'article indéfini (*un/une/des*) sont progressivement devenus obligatoires dans presque tous les cas. Un groupe nominal dont l'existence est niée est un des derniers cas où l'article est devenu obligatoire. Il était encore couramment omis au 18<sup>e</sup> siècle, mais aujourd'hui c'est littéraire et vieilli.

*Rêver* prend d'habitude un complément d'objet indirect : rêver de quelque chose. *Rêver quelque chose* (avec un complément direct) est rare, peut-être pas forcément vieilli parce que c'était déjà rare au 17<sup>e</sup> siècle, mais en tout cas c'est littéraire, on ne l'utilise pas dans la langue de tous les jours.

Donc, en français ordinaire, on dirait « il ne pouvait pas rêver d'une meilleure façon d'occuper son temps libre ». En français littéraire, on peut écrire « il ne pouvait rêver une meilleure façon d'occuper son temps libre ». Et pour faire un peu vieilli on peut omettre *une*.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, in this specific case dropping the *pas* is the normal formulation (it used to be that the negation was expressed solely via *ne*, since the schwa is now rarely pronounced and *ne* does not carry accent, pas nowadays tend to carry the weight of the negation). It's not impossible that the word may be restored to the expression in the future, but it is not a current usage at all.

It is frequent for specific expressions (in all languages) to preserve otherwise obsolete fragments of syntax, grammar and meaning (English example include *fight with*, where *with* originally meant "against" and *hold fast* where *fast* means "firm, secure" *and* is an adverb without *-ly*). In this case, the specific construction falls within a broad group of verb+noun expressions where the noun isn't accompanied by an article (Grevisse, *Le Bon usage 14e ed.*, §587 c).

It **does** present an interesting peculiarity among those expressions: the adjective. Most other cases are constituted of a simple verb+noun pair, and when a qualifying adjective is added, **the article reappears**, which is not the case of the expression *ne pouvoir rêver meilleur X*. As a personal hypothesis, the expression might be an extension of an earlier *ne pouvoir rêver mieux*, i.e. the noun phrase reflects what was originally an adverb.

<strike>Many verbs have or still show hesitation as to the proper way to construct them (just like some do in in English). In fact *rêver* **still** shows hesitation as to whether the correct preposition is *à* or *de*! It was once more common for that verb to also be constructed as a direct transitive verb, especially in the meaning of "meditate, think about, imagine, desire", which this expression may well have been derived from (Grevisse, §296 F). Today the usage is at best highly literary anywhere else but in this expression.</strike>