# When is it that we don't use "ne" along with "pas" in a negative statement?

Tags: grammaire

The rule when you're negating a statement in French is, as I've been taught in A2/B1 French classes, a "ne" + word + "pas" syntax. However, I have seen that that doesn't apply in many sentences, like in the following:

> J'y vais quelquefois, mais **pas souvent**

Why is it so in this case and in what instances do we drop the "ne" *warning* and negate directly with "pas"?

Comment: See [this reply](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/31199/1109) that gives an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A** "Ne + word + pas" is only valid when the word is a verb. There are exceptions though (**B** and **C** below) .

- Il **ne** sait **pas** encore bien parler. (*verb*)
- Les arcs en ciel **ne** sont **pas** visibles pendant bien longtemps après qu'ils ont commené à apparaitre. (*verb*)

**B** In the spoken language of everyday an enormous lot of people use the structure "verb + pas"; "ne" is not used. However, you can choose to use if it pleases you (not to forget : you might displease certain persons if you choose to use it). Remember also that in formal speaking you are considered a sloppy speaker if you do not use it. In a court of law, for instance, it is advised to use "ne" all the time during formal proceedings.

**C** [Boutin-Grammaire](http://www.bertrandboutin.ca/Folder_151_Grammaire/O_a_la_negation.htm) (see this article for much more information on the negation)

> Only "ne" is use in literary French in the following cases.
>
> ■     in  certain proverbs and expressions
> ♦Qui ne dit mot consent.
>
> ■ when using the verbs "*avoir*", "*savoir*" and "*pouvoir*" followed by interrogative "que" and a verb in the infinitive.
> ♦ Il ne sait que dire. (Il ne sait pas quoi dire.)
> ♦ Je n’ai que faire de ses conseils. (Je n’ai rien à faire de vos conseils.)
>
> ■ when using the verbs "*cesser*", "*pouvoir*" and "*savoir*"
> ♦ Je ne saurais vous dire. (Je ne saurais pas vous dire.)

**D** If you need the negation for a noun, adjective or adverb (adverbial locution), then you do not use "ne". Those are however not called properly negative statements but negative locutions.

- Elle recherchait un beau jouet, mais **pas** un jeu éducatif. (*noun group*)
- Elle recherchait un beau jouet **pas** cher. (*adjective*)
- Il se remettait à l'ouvrage, **pas** de bonne volonté, mais avec la détermination de finir ce qui avait été commencé. (*adverbial locution*)
- La roue tournait sans cesse, **pas** rapidement, **pas** sans grincer ni sans de petits à-coups. (*adverb*)

**E** Statements that are ellipses, in particular in answers to questions or in statements that are meant as corrections.

- — Veux-tu de la purée ? (*colloquial*: Tu veux de la purée ?)
  — **Pas** sans beurre… (Je (ne) veux pas de purée sans beurre. *or* Je (n')en veux pas sans beurre)
- — Il est allé au cinéma !
  — **Pas** au cinéma, au théâtre !