# Why is there no 'pas' after the 'ne' in this negative sentence?

Tags: untagged

It's from a short story by the Mauritian writer Sailesh Ramchurn:

> Il lui fallut néanmoins prendre le dessus, être à la hauteur des espérances... Processus de longue haleine, parcours qu'elle n'aurait accompli sans l'appui des autres.

It's the lack of a 'pas' after 'n'aurait' that caught my attention.

Edit: this question has been linked to a question about the use of ‘ne’ without ‘pas’ when employed with the verb ‘pouvoir’. However, this is a different issue and seems to concern the omission of ‘pas’ on account of the presence of ‘sans’ - as explained by Frank in his answer below. It would be nice to see further examples of this specific - ‘ne’ without ‘pas’ because of ‘sans’ - construction.

Comment: Ce n'est pas vraiment une négation, mais *ne* utilisé pour renforce l'idée positive.

Comment: [This](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/886/358) could also answer the question.

Comment: Tom - I can generate more examples, but the construction is quite general: _il n'aurait su aménager sa maison sans son aide_, _il n'aurait pu l'atteindre sans monter sur une échelle_, _il ne l'aurait jamais remarqué sans l'aide d'une longue-vue_, _il ne l'aurait trouvé sans l'aide du détective_ ...

Comment: Thank you Frank, that's most appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the negative phrasing **ne...sans**, the **pas** is optional, and it is a matter of style whether you insert that **pas** or not. It can be felt by some that having both **pas** and **sans** is redundant, or that **ne...sans** is "lighter". But both are perfectly idiomatic and grammatically correct. It may be the case that the form **ne...sans** is somewhat more literary.

The meaning however does not change depending on the presence or absence of that **pas**. To be clear, in both cases, the meaning is that she **did** accomplish something, but that she would not have accomplished it **without** the support of others.

> qu'elle **n**'aurait accompli **sans** l'appui
>
> *that she wouldn't have accomplished without the support*

> qu'elle **n**'aurait **pas** accompli **sans** l'appui
>
> *that she wouldn't have accomplished without the support*

Note also that **ne...pas** is not the only way to negate a sentence in French. One also finds, for example: **ne...plus** ("not anymore"), **ne...jamais** ("not ever"). However, for those, you could *not* add a **pas** in the middle.